# updating a python generator after it has been created

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

Is there any way to do something like this in python 2.7?

```
def scaleit(g, k):
  for item in g:
    yield item*k

promise = ??????
# defines a generator for reference but not use:
# other functions can make use of it,
# but it requires a call to promise.fulfill() to
# define what the generator is going to yield;
# promise raises an error if next() is called 
# before the promise is fulfilled

f = scaleit(promise, 3)
promise.fulfill(range(10))

for item in f:
  print item
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-342.html "Python 2.5 adds a simple way to pass values into a generator."

Comment: I'm aware of `send()` but it's codependent on `yield()`, not independent of it. (in other words `send()` returns the input of `yield()` and `yield()` returns the input of send()`, with the first call to `send()` ignored.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; generators don't run until they're actually iterated, so you can just defer iterating the fulfilled promise's value until requested:

```
class Promise(object):
    def fulfill(self, result):
        self.result = result
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.result)

def scaleit(g, k):
  for item in g:
    yield item*k

promise = Promise()
f = scaleit(promise, 3)
promise.fulfill(range(10))
print list(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
def scaleit(g, k):
  for item in g:
    yield item * k

class Promise(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.g = None

    def fulfill(self, g):
        self.g = iter(g)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return next(self.g)

promise = Promise()

f = scaleit(promise, 3)
promise.fulfill(range(10))

for item in f:
  print item
```

Comment: ooh ah, that may work, let me check if it works for my purposes (or if there is another subtle requirement in my applications that I had forgotten to mention). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `send()` method on generators:

```
def gen():
    reply = yield None
    if not reply:  # reply will be None if send() wasn't called
        raise ValueError("promise not fulfilled")
    yield 5

g1 = gen()
next(g1)  # advance to the first yield
g1.send(True)
print(next(g1))  # prints 5

g2 = gen()
next(g2)
# forget to send
print(next(g2))  # raises ValueError
```

Comment: I don't think that is helpful; see my comment to Patashu's comment to my question.

Comment: Does my edit clarify matters at all? Make `yield` the first statement in your generator, and call `next` on it as soon as it's created. I'm sure you could capture this pattern in a decorator or factory function if it's something you're going to use a lot.